# Extbase: inject repository into domain model

Tags: extbase

I am currently working with Typo3 `6.2.10` and Extbase.

I am trying to inject a repository into my domain model like this:

```
class MyModel extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {
    /**
     * @inject
     * @var \Vendor\Package\Domain\Repository\SomeRepository
     */
    protected $someRepository;
}
```

However, `$this->someRepository` is always `null`. Injecting repositories into controllers always works though.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found the solution myself.

I tried to instantiate the model using `new` keyword which (ofc) **doesn't work**.

I had to use `$this->objectManager->get('\Vendor\Package\Domain\Model\MyModel');`
 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, that you must omit the first \ in the class name when useing the $this->objectManager->get(xxx); or this line will throw an exception in typo3 7.x+.

```
$this->objectManager->get('Vendor\Package\Domain\Model\MyModel');
```

Also the Backslash is an escape character, so it is safer to escape the backslash or just use the static constant of the class

escaped:

```
$this->objectManager->get('Vendor\\Package\\Domain\\Model\\MyModel');
```

Using the static class name:

```
$this->objectManager->get(\Vendor\Package\Domain\Model\MyModel::class);
```

I prefer to use the last method, since you can see if you did a typo (depends on the IDE)